# An inaccessible folder with a random name has appeared in my ~/Pictures folder

Tags: linux, filesystems, arch-linux

Today I noticed a folder within my Pictures folder, that I did not create, and can't access even with root privileges, it is named "3TNksAEHqX" and I can't use `ls` on it, though I can `stat` it, as seen [here](http://pastebin.com/Y0rbr6GV).

I'm wondering what would cause this, and don't necessarily want to delete it, just in case. Moving it (and therefore renaming it) works fine, though it still doesn't allow me to access its contents.

When I *do* try to access its contents, my file manager merely sits there loading, or `ls` just does nothing and forces me to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it.

Shortly after writing this my computer ran out of memory and started swapping; Thunar (my file-manager) had eaten it all up (I suppose it was still trying to access the folder).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you "open" the folder in an editor? Like in Vim: `vim 3TNksAEHqX`. Use a commandline editor. All folders are just files in Linux, so you can open them. You can do the same with a real folder and compare.

Comment: If I try `vim 3TNksAEHqX` it tells me "Illegal file name". Leafpad errors, saying that it's a directory.

Comment: I would move the folder into a new folder. You can try to zip it to keep a copy. Use `df -h` to see how much space you have left before and after doing this. If the folder itself cannot be deleted, you can try to delete the parent folder. No guarantees, but sometimes operations on parent folders work where they don't on the files or folders inside. You can also try chmod or chown and see how that works out.

Comment: I'm slightly more concerned now; trying to remove either the folder, or its parent folder, results in `rm` stalling and my system becoming jerky/less responsive (though, htop doesn't show that process as being particularly active..) 

Chmod and chown did little (I set the permissions to 755 (didn't realise it was already,) and its owner to "ben:users" which I assume is the correct user:group combo.

Comment: I have flagged this question and asked to move it to the linux forum. Maybe if you system is Ubuntu, it should belong in Askubuntu. So please add another tag to the question, with the proper Linux OS in it.

Comment: In the mean time - it's always wise to make a backup of your data while something strange is going on. When making a backup, move this folder somewhere outside of the backup set, so it doesn't get backed up resulting in a system lock.

Comment: Alright. Making a fresh backup now, but I'll wait for a while before attempting to wipe and reinstall (mostly because I'm curious about why this has happened,) in case anybody has any insights.

Comment: I guess this is a temporary folder or file created by some program or service and something went wrong. But I can't tell for sure.

Comment: I've since reinstalled Arch Linux (for unrelated reasons, mostly,) and the file has gone (obviously.)

After the fact, I was advised that perhaps the `unlink` command would have worked. (If anyone comes here looking for a fix, try that.)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and have posted it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/634863/an-inaccessible-directory-with-a-random-name-has-appeared-in-my-home-directory